# Apache Brooklyn 0.8.0-incubation: No handlers could be found for logger "_socket"

Tags: powershell, brooklyn

Every time when I use the VanillaWindowsProcess on AWS the following error message  appears:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "_socket"
```

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WinRM, Brooklyn 0.8.0 is using [winrm4j](https://github.com/cloudsoft/winrm4j) which currently uses [pywinrm](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm) via [jython](http://www.jython.org/) version 2.7-b3.

The error you encountered is coming from jython: described at http://bugs.jython.org/issue2253, and a fix (within python code) at https://hg.python.org/jython/rev/e37122c32d8a.

I suspect a workaround would be to execute a similar thing in jython:

```
log = logging.getLogger("_socket")
log.setLevel(level=logging.WARNING)
```

The long-term solution is to fix it in winrm4j - I've created an issue for this - https://github.com/cloudsoft/winrm4j/issues/5.

(There is a proposal to re-write winrm4j in pure Java, but that hasn't been done yet).

---

I presume this error is benign (i.e. everything else still works)?

Or is the attempt to log an indication that there was a different problem (whose details unfortunately don't reach the log or the console!)?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer Aled! The real interessting thing is that my YAML File with the VanillaWindowsProcess sometimes works and sometimes goes on fire. If it goes on fire the described error appears but I don't see any detailed message in the info log.